# Is there a hardware-independent standard for comparing ML models complexity?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Let us say I have two machine learning models on different machines and one on the cloud. Comparing them using elapsed times of execution does not make sense since they are powered up by different hardware.

Since all models are equations in the core, why is there no such method to calculate the complexity of these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use FLOPS to count the *floating point operatons* and under stand the CPU cycles required for the algorithms you are building.

In python you can do this with a package/module called `pypapi`

[Here is a basic 'hello world' tutorial of `pypapi`](https://bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python/flops/2019/09/27/python-counting-events.html)

If you are working in Pytorch specifically there is a valuable and simple tool, `flopth` that shows you FLOPS for your convolutions. [You can read about its implementation here](https://github.com/vra/flopth)

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You are very welcome!